# Why $http service in AngularJS doesn't find action in controller in APS.Net Web API 2 application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have the application, trying to send request to controller by `$http` service

```
getUserPost: function(id) {
  var posts = [];
  var req = {
       method: "POST",
       url: "/api/getPost",
       data: id
       };
```

I always get the next error:

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:57196/api/getPost'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Post' that matches the request."},"status":404,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/api/getPost","data":0,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"Not Found"}
```

Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class PostController : ApiController
{
    private readonly DataContext _db = new DataContext();

    [Route("getPost")]
    [HttpPost]
    public List<Post> GetPost(string id)
    {
        var posts = new List<Post>();
        if (id != null)
        {
            posts = _db.Posts.Where(x => x.UzytkownikId == int.Parse(id)).ToList();

        }
        return posts;
    }
```

Does anybody know how can I solve this?

Comment: Try `data: JSON.stringify({id: id})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the route for action in wrong way. Try adding **FromBody** to your action in this way:

```
[Route("getPost")]
    [HttpPost]
    public List<Post> GetPost([FromBody]string id)
    {
        var posts = new List<Post>();
        if (id != null)
        {
            posts = _db.Posts.Where(x => x.UzytkownikId == int.Parse(id)).ToList();

        }
        return posts;
    }
```

Comment: OMG, not many time ago it works without this Attribute, but why somethis was changed ? Thanks you for your answer! It helps.